# Automatically transfer funds coming in to a regular Metamask wallet into a Harmony/Gnosis Safe multisig

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm working on a project to release NFTs on an NFT marketplace in time for ETHDenver.

We need to mint NFTs and have the profits automatically go into the Gnosis safe multisig wallet

Do you know if it's possible, and what direction I should look to automatically transfer funds coming in to a regular Metamask wallet into a Harmony/Gnosis Safe multisig?

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have to use a bot that monitors the address for this.

E.g. https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-create-an-ethereum-bot-55aac7534654

Comment: Thank you so much! Much appreciated. :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use thirdweb split contract https://thirdweb.com/

or you can use one of gnosis' partners.

Oxsplits:

https://app.safe.global/share/safe-app?appUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.0xsplits.xyz&chain=eth